# How many ordered terns $(x,y,z)$ can you find such that $xyz=36$?

Tags: number-theory

How many ordered terns $(x,y,z)$ can you find such that $xyz=36$?
Consider $x,y,z ∈ Z$.

I found 8 different sets of numbers $x,y,z$ such that $xyz=36$, they are:

$(3,3,4)(3,6,2)(3,2,2)(36,1,1)(1,18,2)(1,12,3)(1,9,4)(1,6,6)$

But since the terns are ordered, I need to consider the permutations of each of them. That being said, the possible ordered terns should be $3!*8=48$. But I still need to consider terns including negative numbers. Of each tern, just 2 elements can be negative, so that $xyz$ can be positive.

This extends the possibilities to $3!*3*8=144$ which adds up to $48$.

But, the correct answer is $144$, not $168$.

Any help? Where am I wrong?

Comment: You are miscounting, because you don’t have $6$ different orderings of, for example, $(3,3,4)$; there are only three, $(3,3,4)$, $(3,4,3)$, and $(4,3,3)$. So it’s not $3!*8$ even for the purely positive ones.

Comment: My idea: $36=2^2 \times 3^2$. Now set $x=2^a 3^b$, $y=2^c 3^d$, $z= 2^e 3^f$ and then we have to find the number of integer solutions to
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
a+c+e &= 2 \\
b+d+f &= 2
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: (Where did 168 come from? And also, $(3,2,2)$ isn’t right; I think that’s supposed to be $(9,2,2)$...)

Comment: You’re right! There are 36 terns of positive numbers which satisfy the condition. Considering negative numbers the sum become 144, the correct answer. Thanks!